# Webpack alias of named import

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, webpack, tizen

In a react-native app that is also targeting web & Tizen, I'm trying to use webpack aliasing to replace a subcomponent of react-native-web with a custom package.

Relevant webpack config looks as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
      'react-native/Libraries/Alert': 'web/MyOwnAlertComponent', // does not work
      'react-native-web/dist/exports/Alert': 'web/MyOwnAlertComponent', // does not work either
      ...
    }
  }
};
```

The first alias successfully aliases all react-native imports towards react-native-web. The Alert component is also part of react-native, and is imported in code as:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
```

In react-native-web however, this Alert component is only a stub with no implementation. So in the second line of my webpack aliases I wanted to alias the react-native Alert towards my own implementation. This does not seem to work like this.

So how can I point react-native/Libraries/Alert or 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Alert towards my own Alert implementation? I'd like to resolve this, if possible, without touching the original code, which is shared between Android, iOS, tvOS, web & Tizen.

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1026#issuecomment-507443892

Comment: Indeed I use an Alert implementation based on this; but I'm not looking for an implementation, I want to replace react-native-web's stub with a custom one. Preferably using webpack aliasing.

Comment: Did you find any solution?